# Convergence of characteristic functions on hypercube

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces, set-partition

I have a question regarding the following partition of a hypercube $H_{R}(x)$ centered at $x$ with sides of length $R$  in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$:

Consider this hypercube $O = H_{R}(x) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}(\alpha_{i},\beta_{i}) = (\alpha_{1},\beta_{1}) \times \prod_{i=2}^{n}(\alpha_{i}, \beta_{i})$ and the following partition of it:

We divide $(\alpha_{1}, \beta_{1})$ into intervals of length $(\beta_{1}-\alpha_{1})2^{-m}$ where $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Each of these intervals is then subdivided into two parts of equal length $(\beta_{1}-\alpha_{1})2^{-(m+1)}$. The union of the first(resp. the second) subintervals is denoted by $I_{m}$(resp. $J_{m}$). We denote by $$O_{1}^{m} = I_{m} \times \prod_{i=2}^{n}(\alpha_{i}, \beta_{i})$$ $$O_{2}^{m} = J_{m} \times \prod_{i=2}^{n}(\alpha_{i}, \beta_{i})$$ then $\text{meas } O_{1}^{m} = \text{meas }O_{2}^{m} = \frac{1}{2}\text{meas } O$

Can anyone see how it would follow that, if considering the characteristic functions $\chi_{O_{1}^{m}}$ and $\chi_{O_{2}^{m}}$ on the sets $O_{1}^{m}$ and $O_{2}^{m}$ respectively, that we get the result that $\chi_{O_{1}^{m}} \rightharpoonup^{*} \frac{1}{2}$ and $\chi_{O_{2}^{m}} \rightharpoonup^{*} \frac{1}{2}$ in $L^{\infty}(O)$.

Thanks for any assistance, let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: By weak$*$ convergence do you mean that you pair with $L^1$ functions?

Comment: @DimitriosNtalampekos Yes since $L^{1}$ is the dual of $L^{\infty}$

Comment: @LucioD No, it's the other way around: $L^\infty$ is the dual of $L^1$. The dual of $L^\infty$ is the space of absolutely continuous (w.r.t. the lebesgue measure) *finitely additive* measures and $L^1$ corresponds only to the subspace of true (=countably additive) measures. Either way: The weak* topology on $L^\infty$ is nevertheless given by the pairing with $L^1$.

Comment: @JohannesHahn Yes I made a mistake I see, I am using Brezis book of functional analysis, he doesn't go into the dual of $L^{\infty}$ with any great detail, but he does note that $L^{1}$ is a subspace of the dual of $L^{\infty}$. What text do you use to describe the dual of $L^{\infty}$? Also would it then still follow that $f_{n} \rightharpoonup^{*} f$ in $L^{\infty} \Leftrightarrow \langle g, f_{m} \rangle \rightarrow \langle g, f \rangle $? I think that's what you stated at the end of you message?

Comment: Weak-star-convergence $f_i \xrightarrow{w*} f$ in a dual space $X'$ is *defined* as $\langle g,f_i\rangle \to \langle f,g\rangle$ for all $g\in X$. We have the special case $X=L^1$ here. What do you mean by "what text do you use" ? Do you want to have a textbook reference? I think I don't have a real reference for that. I learned that fact from Elstrodt's (german) book "Maß- und Integrationstheorie" where there is a minor remark to that end and I then solved the (implied) exercise to prove that statement for myself.

Comment: @JohannesHahn Okay thanks understood. Do you have any idea how to resolve the above problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have a bounded sequence $f_m$ in $L^\infty$, specifically $\|f_m\|_{L^\infty}\le 1$ for all $m$. For such a sequence, to verify that $f_m\xrightarrow{w^*} f $ it suffices to check that $$\langle g,f_m\rangle \to \langle g,f\rangle \tag{1}$$ for all $g$ in some set $A\subset L^1$ with norm-dense linear span.  Indeed, once we have (1) for $g\in A$, we have it for linear combinations of elements of $A$. And then, given any $h\in L^1$, we can find $g$ in the span of $A$ such that $\|h-g\|_{L^1}\le \epsilon$. It follows that 
$$  | \langle h,f_m\rangle - \langle h,f\rangle | \le 2\epsilon + | \langle g,f_m\rangle - \langle g,f\rangle |$$
and since $\epsilon$ is arbitrarily small, $| \langle h,f_m\rangle - \langle h,f\rangle | \to 0$.

It remains to pick a convenient set $A$ with norm-dense span in $L^1$. I suggest the set of characteristic functions of dyadic rectangles. With this choice, you'll  see that  for every $g\in A$, 
$$\int gf_m = \frac12 \int g$$ 
for all $m$ large enough. This shows (1),

Comment: Thanks for your response, interesting answer. I unfortunately have some questions. If you are willing, maybe you can send me an email at dlucio50@yahoo.com, and we can correspond via email. Could you please give some detail about your choice of dyadic rectangles and how this would give the desired $\langle g, f_{m} \rangle \rightarrow \langle g, f \rangle$ for all $g$ in $A$ as you stated. I'm having difficulty finding a good reference for how exactly you would define dyadic rectangles simply.

Comment: Could you plz describe the 'set of characteristic functions of dyadic functions' that you are referring to?

Comment: @Fundamental Nice answer. I suppose for the last part of your proof where you state $$\int gf_{m} = \frac{1}{2}\int g$$ the reasoning is as follows: Take the case for proving just $\chi_{O_{1}^{m}} \rightharpoonup^{*} \frac{1}{2}$. Let $f_{m} := \chi_{O_{1}^{m}}$ and $g = \chi_{A_{i}}$ where $A_{i}$ is a dyadic cube. Then $\int gf_{m} = \int \chi_{A_{i}\cap O_{1}^{m}} = \text{meas}(A_{i}\cap O^{m}_{1}) = \frac{1}{2}\text{meas}(A_{i}) = \frac{1}{2}\int g$.

Comment: @Fundamental The problem is what if the dyadic cube $A_{i}$ is taken so small that $A_{i} \subset O^{m}_{1}$? Then $\text{meas}(A_{i}\cap O^{m}_{1}) = \text{meas}(A_{i})= \int g$. What do you think?